# Chisquare statistic not working python

Tags: python, chi-squared-test

*code is Python 3*

I have a dataset of 5000 counts that I need to plot, compare to a Gaussian fit, and calculate the Chisquare statistic.
The code I have used to plot my data is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

sb.distplot(a=counts, bins=48, fit=stats.norm, 
            kde=False, norm_hist=False,
            hist_kws = {'label':'Measured  
      Counts','edgecolor':'black','alpha':0.15},
            fit_kws = {'label':'Gaussian'})

plt.legend();
```

[image]

The data follows a Poisson random distribution but it has a mean of 49 so it should approximate to a Gaussian (which it does). When I try to calculate the Chisquare statistic I get a value of roughly 2000, and a p-value of 0.

My code for calculating the chisquare is

```
stats.chisquare(f_obs=counts1,  
f_exp=poisson.rvs(np.linspace(33,68,5000),  
mean))
```

I use this linspace because the frequency from 33-68 is at least 5.
Are my expected values suitable for use in this function, and if not, what should I use to create a usable set of expected values?

Comment: Can you show some plots?

Comment: @MisterMak Edited to include plot

Comment: You seem to have created a dataset large enough to demonstrate that a Poisson(49) variable does *not* have a Gaussian distribution.  Why is there any problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what library you are using, but if it is scipy stats, `poisson.rvs(x, mu)` returns a list of random variables, not the pdf.  Why don't you try plotting to check what it looks like?  Might be better to use `poisson.pmf(k, mu)` or `norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)` (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html).